#  is a set and ∗ is a binary operation on  such that the following conditions are satisfied. Prove that G is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

is a set and $∗$ is a binary operation on  such that the following conditions are
satisfied.

i) $ ∗ ( ∗ ) = ( ∗ ) ∗  ∀,  ∈ $.

ii) There exists an element $$ in $$ such that $ ∗  = $.

iii) For each $ ∈ $ there exists  in  such that $ ∗  = $.

iv) For $, ,  ∈ $ if $ ∗  = $ and $ ∗  = $ then $ = $.

Prove that $$ is a group.

So, I proved this by simply showing that $e$ is a right identity of $a$, and that $b$ is also a right inverse of $a$. Now, I'm not sure whether that is sufficient.

Because the problem already says that the conditions are satisfied for the set, and $*$ is a binary operation I do not really understand what else I should prove. Any help would be appreciated.

The definition in the book I'm referring:

> Let  be a non-empty set and $∗$ be a binary operation defined in . Then  together with $∗$ denoted by $(,∗)$ is a group if the following three axioms are satisfied by $$ and $∗$.
>
> 1: $∗$ is associative on $$.
>
> 2: $∃  ∈ $ such that $ ∗  =  ∀ ∈ .$
>
> 3: For each $ ∈ , ∃′ ∈ $ such that $′ ∗  = .$
>
> The element  is called a left identity of $(,∗)$ and ′ is called a left inverse of  in $(,∗)$.

Comment: That's all there was to prove. Most of the axioms are satisfied by the information you're given.

Comment: What definition of a group are you using?

Comment: @Shaun This is the def. in the book:   Let  be a non-empty set and ∗ be a binary operation defined in . Then  together with ∗
denoted by (,∗) is a group, if the following three axioms are satisfied by  and ∗.
1: ∗ is associative on .
2: ∃  ∈  such that  ∗  =  ∀ ∈ .
3: For each  ∈ , ∃′ ∈  such that ′ ∗  = .
The element  is called a left identity of (,∗) and ′ is called a left inverse of  in (,∗).

Comment: @CyclotomicField Oh great then! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Thank you, @KKR. I suggest you [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @Shaun I hope now it's alright! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Other users might benefit from knowing which book you are referring to, so you could include that, too, but, yes, it is otherwise fine, @KKR :)